# Sending data back from a Node server to an iOS device (Using Swift)

Tags: ios, node.js, swift

At the moment the code on my iOS (Swift) side is send a POST request to my Node server, which is returning a status code of 200 -- as it hit the server.

**Question:
*What I'm trying to do is return data back to the device, and in this case send back 'nice'.***

Node listening for Post requests:

```
app.post('/test.json', function (req, res){
    console.log("Hit!");
    res.send('nice');
});
```

and Swift:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // create the request & response
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://serverlocation.com/path")!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval: 5)
    var response: NSURLResponse?
    var error: NSError?

    // create some JSON data and configure the request
    let jsonString = "json=[{\"str\":\"Hello\",\"num\":1},{\"str\":\"Goodbye\",\"num\":99}]"
    request.HTTPBody = jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    // send the request
    NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response, error: &error)

    // look at the response
    println("The response: \(response)")
    if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
        println("HTTP response: \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
    } else {
        println("No HTTP response")
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: @ChrisH "What I'm trying to do is also return data back to the device, and in this case send back 'nice'."

Comment: So you are asking where the data is on iOS? Try `let data = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest....`

Comment: @ChrisH when printing data I get: <6e696365>

Comment: That's because you're trying to print a NSData object, make it a string with the NSString method - initWithData:encoding: and then print the string

Comment: Btw, loading data synchronously will make your UI unresponsive which is kind of annoying in any app, try doing it asynchronously.

Comment: Got it, you can post that as the answer!

Comment: @MarkE Would it be better to send these requests from the ViewController or AppDelegate? I'm very new to iOS dev and still trying to figure out when to use each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the response body you need to store the data returned by the method `sendSynchronousRequest`, then make it a string since `sendSynchronousRequest` returns an instance of a NSData object.
It would be something like this:

```
let body = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response, error: &error)
let bodyStr = NSString(data: body!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
print(bodyStr)
```

That said, I would recommend against using synchronous request to server, this will block the UI until complete which may be annoying to end users. To make this an asynchronous request you can change the method `+ sendSynchronousRequest:returningResponse:error:` for the method `+ connectionWithRequest:delegate:`. Then make the view controller your delegate and implement in it the methods:
`- connection:didReceiveResponse:`
`- connection:didReceiveData:`
To catch the response and handle the data in it. Also don't forget to add `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` to the declaration of the `ViewController` or whichever the class that you set as the delegate.

About the question in the comments:

> Would it be better to send these requests from the ViewController or AppDelegate?

Where to put this code depends on what data you are retrieving. Generally is a bad idea to put something in the `AppDelegate` unless is something you want to do no matter what and no matter what is happening in the views.
Placing it on the `ViewController` would be a good idea if it is retrieving information related to something you are going to show in this specific view. Otherwise if the information is more related to something like a data structure it would make more sense to make another class which retrieves the data from server and process it in an appropriate form for this data structure.